# How to get members from private Slack channel?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I use
`https://slack.com/api/conversations.members?channel=[redacted]&token=[redacted]`

I get the channel id from URL.

Response

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "channel_not_found"
}
```

Comment: please do not to post your token credentials.

Comment: xoxb-1111-1111-11111111 is it looks like real token ? ) @ewong

Comment: I don't know.  it's better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error either when the channel doesn't exist or your bot doesn't have the required scope and access.

If you are using a bot token, make sure that you have [`groups:read`](https://api.slack.com/scopes/groups:read) scope. Your bot needs to be a member of the channel. You can invite your bot by using `/invite @botusername` command in the private channel.

Comment: Does scope mean permission?

Comment: For ease of understanding, you could say so. More specifically though, your application asks for permission from the user to access the specified scope. e.g. `groups:read` scope lets an app `view basic information about private channels that your slack app has been added to` (quoting from its documentation page)